# How to deploy a laravel application that will be accessed over a LAN on a windows server?

Tags: laravel

I am tasked to develop a laravel project for our company. I have to deploy it within the company's network only. It is my first time to do it and haven't find any good source of instruction so far. I hope you can help me with this. I am using XAMPP for this one. And the machine runs on a Windows Server 2016.

Comment: .Check this source https://jimfrenette.com/2016/09/laravel-iis-windows-install/

Answer (score 0):

Laravel applications are easy to install on IIS. You can use the url_rewrite extension to import the rules from the .htaccess file. Other than that it is really no different than deploying to any other server.

You can also use your company's local DNS to point to the server if you wish to access it via https://my-app.company.com.

Answer (score 0):

May sure you all are one in common network 
`sudo php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 81` (you can change the port if you want)

Other people will be able to access with you'r IP address `http://your-pc-id-address:81`